# How can I suppress constexpr warnings in MSVC?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Let's say I have a Square function that I deliberately want to overflow:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>

constexpr uint64_t Square(uint64_t val)
{
    return val * val;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr uint64_t val = Square(0x100000000);
}
```

This will trigger a warning 4307 (overflow warning) at every constexpr call, which makes sense--it can evaluate if each call will cause the overflow or not.
However, trying to suppress the warning in the function definition doesn't seem to have any effect. We still get all the same warnings if we do this:

```cpp
constexpr uint64_t Square(uint64_t val)
{
#pragma warning(suppress:4307)
    return val * val;
}
```

Instead we have to suppress the warning every time we call the function, which is undesirable:

```
int main()
{
#pragma warning(suppress:4307)
    constexpr uint64_t val = Square(0x100000000);
}
```

The best option I could find was creating a macro that wraps the call, and calling that:

```cpp
#define SafeSquare(val) \
__pragma(warning(suppress:4307)) \
Square(val)
```

This does not play nice with parameter packs, though.

Short of disabling the warning globally, is there any way to disable the warning for Square?

Note: ["integer constant overflow" warning in constexpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658794/integer-constant-overflow-warning-in-constexpr) touches on similar topics, but the focus there was writing code to work around causing a warning, whereas I want to know specifically if the warning can be disabled somehow.

Comment: Relevant: This [has been discussed on the MSVC Dev Community site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/211134/unsigned-integer-overflows-in-constexpr-functionsa.html), and was [recognised as a known bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/comments/211580/view.html).  It doesn't appear to have been fixed yet, unfortunately.

Comment: Does wrapping the function in #pragma waring(push) #pragma waring(disable : 4307) /* function definition */ #pragma warning(pop) instead work?

Comment: @JustinTime: Aww man, over a year with no fix... I think that answers my question though, thanks.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: No, it'll behave exactly the same as ```#pragma warning(suppress:4307)```.

Comment: Yeah... hopefully it's just bizarrely difficult for them to track down, and hasn't been forgotten.  You're welcome, though.

Comment: I tried this in vc2019 and do not get a warning even using std::numeric_limits<uint64_t>::max().

Comment: @SoronelHaetir: Could you show me your example? This is failing for me, both on the latest VC++ and on godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/35anPl

Comment: note that the name should be `square` instead of `pow`

Comment: @phuclv Edited the question to use Square, thanks.

Comment: This appears to be no longer reproducible